# Monitor Options

Tags: monitor

We recently upgraded to 12.04 on an oldish system that still has a CRT monitor. We now find that certain panes won't fit the screen shape, probably due to the monitor type being set as 'widescreen laptop'...

We can't change this as no other monitor type appears in the set-up list, evn when you use the 'find monitor' option.

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the resolution perhaps the resolution you're using is too big since the crt monitor is an old model probably can only take up to 800x600 always on the display screen just change the resolution to one that is smaller i would recommend you to try with 800x600

Comment: Good answer - thanks! Just tried it, but no difference really noticeable. However, as you raised this point immediately I might just re-set the screen resolution and let it run for a few days and a few shutdowns. Thank you again.